# No sound from Java web applet

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, audio, java, web

Using Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers on Ubuntu 9.10, I am unable to get any sound out from Java (version 6 update 15) on Runescape or [WebSDR](http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/).

I'm only interested in getting WebSDR working and Runescape was the only other web applet I knew would have sound.

Sound does work in a test applet I downloaded when run from the command line so it seems to be a web specific issue.

Anyone else encountered or solved this or a similar issue? Are there any better applets out there that I can use to test my sound?

Answer (score 1):

There is some information about sound in Java applets at [the Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/sound.html) however it is mainly aimed at Java programmers.

It does show that sound can be produced in various ways, which might explain why some sounds work and others don't.

The usual issue for sound playback is lack of the right `codec` for the sound format.

It is also possible that Java applets which are signed by the author (not all are) are granted higher privileges.

Try looking in the **java console** for error messages relating to sound.
See the Java Glossary entry for `Console`